# Setting ComboBox SelectedValue

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

My Winform `ComboBox` is bound this way:

```
this.myComboBox.DataSource = myDS;
this.myComboBox.DisplayMember = PropertyHelper<MyType>.NameOf(i => i.prop1);
this.myComboBox.ValueMember = PropertyHelper<MyType>.NameOf(i => i.prop2);
```

`myDS` does include a `MyType` element whose `prop2` value = `myType.prop2val`.

I am trying to set the `Combobox` item with this item.
1st attempt:

```
myComboBox.SelectedValue = (int)myType.prop2val;
```

This does not work : it sets `myComboBox.SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` to null.

2nd attempt:

```
myComboBox.SelectedItem = ((List<MyType>)myComboBox.DataSource)
                         .FirstOrDefault(a => a.prop2 == myType.prop2val);
```

This line works but I find it ugly.

I am pretty sure that I missed something to make the first attempt work.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you include this.myComboBox.DataBind(); ?

Comment: `myComboBox.SelectedItem = myType.prop2val;`

Comment: @Alander,isn't  DataBind() for webForms?

Comment: the combobox lists all the elements of the DS, it just does not set the correct element with the first code line.

Comment: What is type of `myType.prop2val`?

Comment: @Fabio : it is actually my entity PK. It's a long? that I cast to int to match myComboBox.SelectedValue type.

Comment: If `myComboBox.ValueMember` equal to name of correct property then and `myType.prop2val` is in the combobox list(as second approach prove) then line `myComboBox.SelectedValue = (int)myType.prop2val;` should select correct item and `myCombobox.SelectedItem` should return selected item. Please check that `PropertyHelper<MyType>.NameOf(i => i.prop2)` actually return correct value

Comment: @flavio : yes, PropertyHelper<MyType>.NameOf(i => i.prop2) does return "prop2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most obviously reason for your problem is that type of `myType.prop2` and type of value given in `myComboBox.SelectedValue` are different types.

As you said in the comments type of `MyType.prop2` is `long`, but for `SelectedValue` you cast value to `int`.

```
myComboBox.SelectedValue = (int)myType.prop2val;
```

I didn't understand why you need to cast it to `int`, but anyway types for property in `ValueMember` and type for `SelectedValue` should be same to satisfy equality.

ComboBox compares values as values of type `object`, so boxed value of type `long` will not be equal to boxed value of type `int`.
ComboBox comparison code looks something like below

```
int givenSelectedValue = 2;

object selectedValue = givenSelectedValue;  // boxed to object type
for (int i = 0; i < internalDataSourceList.Count; i++) 
{
    object itemValue = // get value of list[i] and property from ValueMember
    if (selectedValue.Equals(itemValue)) 
    {
        return i; // Return index of selected item
    }
}

// if not found
return -1;
```

Comment: yees!! I am not sure anymore on earth why I set this erronous cast in the first time. I Removed it and it works like a charm.
Thx a ton Fabio!